# Error: could not find function "lang_unnamespace"

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang, tidyselect

I am getting the error [here in this Travis build](https://travis-ci.org/ropensci/drake/jobs/343973845#L1258), and I cannot reproduce it locally. Yes, I realize that I do not have a minimal reproducible example, but I do know that it happens within `tidyselect::vars_select()`. Has anyone else encountered this before? I cannot find any mention of `lang_unnamespace()` in a Google search.

Comment: If I run `getAnywhere("lang_unnamespace")` I see that it comes from the `rlang` package. It's not exported from that package so it's not meant to be used directly.

Comment: Hmm... when I run `getAnywhere("lang_unnamespace")`, I see `no object named 'lang_unnamespace' was found"`. I have `rlang` 0.2.0. What about you?

Comment: I'm running `rlang_0.1.4`

Answer (score 0):

See if modifying your [travis yaml](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/blob/master/.travis.yml) to include the dev versions of the tidyverse packages help.

It looks like you're *not* calling `rlang::lang_unnamespace()` directly, correct?  That function appears to have been removed, but `tidyselect::vars_select()` is still trying to call it.

I arbitrarily went back to the beginning of the year to see this [old version](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/blob/383a1e1138268c270618dec3e3a967cb3bd52658/R/expr-lang.R#L525-L533).

The file doesn't even exist in [today's version](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/tree/3c42b3c99abd4951d77931353b9e83effb736c0c/R).

Comment: Correct, I am not calling `rlang::lang_unnamespace()` directly. It's weird: both locally and on Travis, `rlang` 0.2.0 and `tidyselect` 0.2.3 are installed. Clearing the Travis cache seems to cause the first set of bulids to complete normally, but then the ones after that quit with the same error.

Comment: A lot of the tidyverse packages were updated on CRAN yesterday.  Travis might be pulling from different servers, with different versions.  If you specify the dev location (which is GitHub in this case), you might get a consistent version.  Using the `r_github_packages` argument in https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I see that the `rlang` CRAN checks are a mix between 0.1.6 and 0.2.0. I may just have to wait a bit.

Comment: The error went away on Travis, but now it's on AppVeyor: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ropensci/drake/build/1.0.564.